# Using hyperref to refer to unnumbered objects

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I want to refer to a subsection, but my subsections and sections are not numbered. So I know I cannot use `~\ref{}` and I should use hyperef, but it doesn't appear as I want. In the text I have:

dataset described in the ata].

How Should I use hyperref?

This is the code I am using:

```
dataset described in the \hyperref{sec:datasets}[Data].
```

and

```
\subsection*{Datasets}
\label{sec:datasets}
```

Comment: Please add and [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) which replicates your problem.

Answer (score 6):

An unnumbered entity cannot be referenced by number. There are alternatives:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section*{First section}
\label{sec:first}

Reference by title: \nameref{sec:first}\\    
Page reference: \pageref{sec:first}\\
Arbitrary text: \hyperref[sec:first]{This section}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks so much. I have done that. But it doesn't appear correctly.

Comment: @Erin The syntax of `\hyperref` in the question is wrong. First comes the optional argument in *square brackets* with the label name, then the mandatory argument in *curly braces*: `\hyperref[sec:datasets]{Data}`