# How to reference to "Part #" page that was created by \part*{}?

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing

I basically have this:

```
\documentclass{book}

% PART I PAGE
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textsc{Part I: PART ONE TITLE}}
\part*{\textsc{Part I: PART ONE TITLE}}

%PART I PROLOGUE
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textsc{Prologue to Part I}}
\chapter*{\textsc{Prologue to Part I}}
\markboth{\textsc{Prologue to Part I}}{\textsc{Prologue to Part I}}
\label{ch:Part1_prologue}
```

I would like to reference the page that was created by this -- it is a page that simply says "Part I: PART ONE TITLE" in the middle of the page. How do I do this?

I tried adding `\label{Part I}` after the `\part*{}` command, but it references to the last section in the chapter before it...

Comment: why are you using an unnumbered `\part*` and then numbering by hand?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Because I want to remove the numbering without removing it from the table of contents... My main chapters are numbered, but the epilogues, "Part #", and prologues are not.

Comment: but if you have no part number (which is fine) why reference it as Part 1 ?

Comment: I do want them to have part numbers, but not contribute to the numbering of the other stuff in the TOC, so I had to use unnumbered `\part*` and manually number them. [For the purposes of the question I posted, "...Part I..." is simply arbitrary text...]

Comment: Now it's less clear to me.  The part numbering doesn't usually contribute to the numbering of the other stuff in the TOC.  Chapters (the next level down) continue regardless of the parts.

Comment: My apologies, I was not clear and perhaps misspoke. You are correct -- if I use `\part` instead of `\part*`, I see that it shows up in the TOC as part-dependent-numbering, e.g. 1 Chapter_1_title, then 2 Chapter_2_title, then I Part_1_title, 3 Chapter_3_title...

I used `\part*` because I do not want it to be numbered in the TOC (which means having an `I` before Part_1_title).

Additionally, I have Prologues and Epilogues for each part, and these are chapters. I use `\chapter*` for these to avoid impacting the numbering of the main chapters. Using `\part*` and `\chapter*` looks nice in TOC.

Comment: Continuing my above comment, this is not to say that this is the best solution possible for my case -- I am by no means a master of LaTeX, and I have not proactively tried to replace using `\part*` for my parts and `\chapter*` for my prologues/epilogues..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry -- I realize now that this is essentially just referencing an unnumbered object.

I followed [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/318261/) -- specifically I added a `\label` and used `\hyperref[]{}` (since I want it to say "Part I" and not "Part I: PART ONE TITLE").